# Sorting a vector of structs twice

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

Let's say I have a vector of structs,

```
struct foo {
 int num;
 char s;
};

vector<foo> vec;
```

`s` can be one of the three values: `a`, `b` or `c` while `num` can be any positive or negative integer.

What I want is to

first, sort the vector according to `num`, and then, for each set of repeating values of `num`, sort them according to `s` where (a < b < c).

I understand the first step is fairly easy and can be achieved by predicate function,

```
bool compare (foo &a, foo &b) {
 if(a.num < b.num) return true;
 else return false;
}
```

and `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare)`

What I am stuck at is the second part. To sort repeating values in the vector according to `s`. I've tried adding another condition in this predicate and creating a separate predicate for another sort step, but I seem to be missing something.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: *for each set of repeating values of num* -- `std::sort` will not help you here if you mean by "repeating" that the values are the same and follow each other in the container.  Those two items given to the sorting predicate could have been obtained from any of the items in the container.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I thought so. `unique` and `set` seem to remove repeating elements. What I want it is to sort the sub-vector according to `s`

Comment: If you want to sort by `num` but for ties with `num`, you want to sort by `s`, then the solution is straightforward using `std::tie`.

Comment: use *std::pair* `bool compare (foo &a, foo &b) { return make_pair(a.num,a.s) < make_pair(b.num,b.s); }`

Comment: You can use [std::stable_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) for the second sort so as not to disturb the first sort.

Comment: @rafix07 -- Basically the same as using `std::tie`.

Comment: yes, if he uses c++11 or newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your sort function to something like :

```
    bool compare (foo &a, foo &b) {
       if(a.num < b.num) return true;
       else if(a.num == b.num) return a.s < b.s;

       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is simple, but if you want to extend your `struct` to more members and sort based on some cascading logic (i.e. if the first 2 members are equal, sort on the third, if the first 3 members are equal, sort on the fourth item, etc.), the code may get cumbersome.  That would then be a good reason to use `std::tie`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort based on `num`, and if both `num` values are equal in the predicate, then sort by `s`, this can be accomplished by using [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
#include <tuple>
bool compare (foo &a, foo &b) 
{
   return std::tie(a.num, a.s) < std::tie(b.num, b.s);
}
```

If you are using a C++ 98 standard compiler and not C++ 11, then the same thing can be accomplished using `make_pair`

```
#include <utility>
bool compare (foo &a, foo &b) 
{
   return std::make_pair(a.num, a.s) < std::make_pair(b.num, b.s);
}
```

---

My preference, if available, is `std::tie` over using `std::make_pair`.  The reason is that if you add a third member to your `struct`, and you want to sort on this new member if both `num` and `s` are equal, the code using `std::tie` is easier to update, as `make_pair` only works for two values:

```
#include <tuple>
bool compare (foo &a, foo &b) 
{
   return std::tie(a.num, a.s, a.something_else) < std::tie(b.num, b.s, b.something_else);
}
```

Comment: You can pass argument by const references BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not recommending the approach but you *could* use two invocations of sort: one sort on the inner elements followed by a stable sort on the outer elements (it is bound to be slower, though):

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
          [](foo const& f0, foo const& f1){ return f0.s < f1.s; });
std::stable_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
          [](foo const& f0, foo const& f1){ return f0.num < f1.num; });
```

---

Another approach would first sort the elements  according to the outer condition and then sort the equal ranges (i.e., equal according to the outer condition) according to the inner condition:

```
auto outer_cond = [](foo const& f0, foo const& f1) {
    return f0.num < f1.num;
};

// sort elements according to the outer condition
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), outer_cond);

for (auto first = vec.begin(); first != vec.end();) {
    // find equal range
    first = std::adjacent_find(first, vec.end(),
                 [](foo const& f0, foo const& f1) { return f0.num == f1.num; });
    auto last = first;
    std::tie(first, last) = std::equal_range(first, vec.end(), *first, outer_cond);

    // sort equal range according to the inner condition
    std::sort(first, last,
              [](foo const& f0, foo const& f1) { return f0.s < f1.s; });

    first = last;
}
```

However, sorting the entire range with a suitable predicate is probably most efficient.